# How can I bind to something other than a property in ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I'm working on a flashcard app. I have these two models: Deck and Card.

Deck:

```
 public class Deck
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
     }
```

Card:

```
 public class Card
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Front { get; set; }
        public string Back { get; set; }
     }
```

In my user's HomeViewModel, they see a list of their decks in a listview. In each row, they see the Deck's Name, the number of cards it has, and then a button with the option to study, edit, or delete each deck.

My question is about displaying the number of cards the Deck has. Right now, my HomeViewModel looks like this:

```
public class HomeViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private int _count;
        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return _count;
            }
            set
            {
                _count = Count;
                OnPropertyChanged("Count");
            }
        }
        private readonly IDeckManager _deckManager;
        public CreateDeckViewModel _createDeckViewModel { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Deck> Decks { get; set; }

        public HomeViewModel(CreateDeckViewModel createDeckViewModel, IAuthenticator authenticator, IDeckManager deckManager)
        {
            //Decks = all of the current users decks
            _deckManager = deckManager;

            Decks = new ObservableCollection<Deck> 
                      (_deckManager.getDecks(authenticator.CurrentUser.Id).Result);
            
            //the result comes in, but I must be binding incorrectly
            foreach (Deck deck in Decks)
            {
                  Count = _deckManager.getCardCount(deck.Id).Result;
            }
            _createDeckViewModel = createDeckViewModel;
        }
    }
```

My IDeckManager interacts with my database and returns the count of Cards within a Deck.

My View has a ItemsSource of Deck. For the Name column I simply use

```
Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
```

but since Deck has no property for the number of Cards that it has, I am not sure what to bind to. This is what I currently have for the count:

```
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:HomeViewModel}}, 
                    Path=Stuff, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, FallbackValue=500}"
```

I also tried calling the getCardCount method with the Id of the current Deck in a foreach loop and a converter, but the converter constructor can't accept parameters and therefore the instance of my IDeckManager, and I can't get the foreach loop to work.

Is there another option here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have the deck as the DataContext, and you can bind to the HomeViewModel through FindAncestor, You could use an IMultiValueConverter and send both to it, do the calculations you need and return the number of cards.

```
public class DeckToCountConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int count = 0;
        if(values.Length == 2 && values[0] is Deck && values[1] is HomeViewModel)
        {
            Deck deck =  values[0] as Deck;
            HomeViewModel vm = values[1] as HomeViewModel;
            count = vm.GetCountByDeckId(deck.Id);
        }

        return count;
    }

 
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

since your IDeckManager is private you would either need to make it public, write a GetCountByDeckId method (what I did here) or have some kind of dictionary of counts by id (the count in the code re-assigns to count, so it always has the count of the last deck it calculated).

```
public class HomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public int GetCountByDeckId(int deckId)
    {
        return _deckManager.getCardCount(deckId).Result;
    }
}
```

and in case you need a reference for multibinding to a ListView:
[Multibinding within a list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046281/multibinding-within-a-list-view)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wasn't aware that I could send (the instance of?) my HomeViewModel to the converter. Now I am struggling with the XAML syntax for that, I'm not sure what the Path for that should be since it must be a Binding, although the ID is working fine. Right now, for sending the HomeViewModel I have: 

```<Binding Path="???" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:HomeViewModel}}" />```

Comment: Since I can't edit my last comment, I will say that I changed my Binding to:

```<Binding Mode="OneWay" Source="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:HomeViewModel}}" />```

and I am closer, I actually get a value at values[1] but it is as a RelativeSource object, so I am currently messing with that trying to figure out if my Source is wrong somehow. When I used RelativeSource and not Source, I get an empty PropertySource object in the converter.

Comment: assuming HomeViewModel is the dataContext for the window\usercontrol,
`<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MyWindow}" Path="DataContext" />` should be good for you..